# Android Http Connection to Simple PHP script

Tags: php, android, http

I'm new to android and would like someone to help me write a simple application in which I could send the appropriate order through two buttons to this simple script in PHP that would allow control of light through RPi.

```
<?php
$setmode17 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 17 out");
if(isset($_GET['on'])){
$gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 1");
echo "LED is on";
}
else if(isset($_GET['off'])){
$gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 0");
echo "LED is off";
}
?>
```

Android code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LightsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights);


        final Button buttonOn = findViewById(R.id.lights_on_button);
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        final Button buttonOff = findViewById(R.id.lights_off_button);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Light is connected via relay channel module through GPIO ports and and I control it through the python shell.

Comment: Ok. Show part of your android code where you set the on click listeners.

Comment: And tell how Android device and raspi are connected.

Comment: What is the url of your php file?

Comment: http://192.168.100.26/gpio.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution if anybody will need it:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class LightsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lights);


    final Button buttonOn = findViewById(R.id.lights_on_button);
    buttonOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Background_get().execute("on=ON");
        }
    });

    final Button buttonOff = findViewById(R.id.lights_off_button);
    buttonOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Background_get().execute("off=OFF");
        }
    });
}

private class Background_get extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            /* Change the IP to the IP you set in the arduino sketch */
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.100.26/gpio.php?" + params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                result.append(inputLine).append("\n");

            in.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            return result.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}